# Selenium webdriver with JAVA

Tags: java, eclipse, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, nullpointerexception

**When I run this code.  I am getting this error `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException` .Can anyone tell me how to fix it?

```
package Insights;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
public class Test_getinsights {
    static WebDriver driver;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception  {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C://selenium-2.53.0/chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://getinsights.co");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        //Login//
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div/nav/div/div[2]/ul/li[7]/a")).click();

        //Login_page//
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='form']/div[1]/input")).sendKeys("testgetinsight@gmail.com");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/form/div[2]/input")).sendKeys("airloyal");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/form/div[3]/div[2]/button")).click();

        //Create_survey//
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='rootId']/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/button")).click();

        //Create_Question//
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(700, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/button[2]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='rootId']/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div/button[2]")).click();
        System.out.println("driver=" + driver);
        ****driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='question 14998']/div/textarea")).sendKeys("Which is the best website to learn JAVA?");****  // Null pointer Exception//
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='rootId']/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[5]/button")).click();

        //Post_Question
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".clear.openTextStyle.ng-pristine.ng-untouched.ng-invalid.ng-invalid-required")).sendKeys("Java");

        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".launch-btn.ng-binding")).click();

        driver.quit();
        driver.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is any element for this statement. So please add check for null before invoking sendKeys

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='question 14998']/div/textarea"));
if ( element != null ){
  element.sendKeys("Which is the best website to learn JAVA?")
}else 
//Do some thing 
}
```

Comment: ** i have done the same.Now iam getting "No such window exception" **

Comment: This is a common problem . You have use explicit wait or implicit wait 
 driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)  or need to use  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 2); and wait.until

Answer (score 0):

HI please try like below with a slight change your code started to working

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception  {
            //System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C://selenium-2.53.0/chromedriver.exe");
            WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(700, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.get("https://getinsights.co");
            driver.manage().window().maximize();

        //Login//
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div/nav/div/div[2]/ul/li[7]/a")).click();

        //Login_page//
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='form']/div[1]/input")).sendKeys("testgetinsight@gmail.com");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/form/div[2]/input")).sendKeys("airloyal");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/form/div[3]/div[2]/button")).click();

        //Create_survey//
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='rootId']/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/button")).click();

        //Create_Question//

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/button[2]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='rootId']/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div/button[2]")).click();
        System.out.println("driver=" + driver);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@placeholder='Type your Question']")).sendKeys("Which is the best website to learn JAVA?"); 
 // Null pointer Exception //here i simply changed the xpath and its working 
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='rootId']/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[5]/button")).click();

        //Post_Question
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".clear.openTextStyle.ng-pristine.ng-untouched.ng-invalid.ng-invalid-required")).sendKeys("Java");

        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".launch-btn.ng-binding")).click();

        driver.quit();
```

// also please do not use driver instance after you have used driver.quit();
        }

Answer (score 0):

At last steps you are using below code:

```
  driver.quit();
  driver.close();
```

When you use driver,quit() it close all browsers and destroy session, so when you add driver.close() it generate  null pointer exception. you never add any selenium webdriver code after driver.quit().
If you want to add both then add in below sequence:

```
  driver.close();
  driver.quit();
```